# Strange behavior checking for Web Storage availability

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

```
if(typeof(Storage)!==undefined) {
    // Web storage support
    if(localStorage.hashes != "") {
        var hashes = jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.hashes);
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            // Do stuff here
        }
    }
    else {
        var hashes = [];
    }
}
else {
    // No web storage support
}
```

I don't really know what's going on, but when I try to load the page with this code from a device for the first time, the rest of my code doesn't work the way it should. However, if I comment it out then visit the page for the first time everything works. I can then uncomment it, reload the page, and everything will continue to work. This is really the best I can describe what's happening.

Comment: the `typeof` operator returns a string (e.g. `'undefined'`), which will never be equal to `undefined`. Also, you should not declare variables inside of if/else blocks as javascript does not have block scope.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I made the changes, but I'm still experiencing the same issues.

Comment: Other small things - you should consider using the native `JSON.parse()` instead of `$.parseJSON`, `localStorage.getItem()` instead of bracket/dot notation, and you never push `hashes` into `localStorage` in the `else` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! So in the above code I check if they had localStorage available, and if they do, I just assume that they have some hashes stored in there. This obviously creates a problem on their first visit as they wouldn't have any hashes saved yet. So I have to check if they have any, if they do, then do the for loop, otherwise just set it to an empty array. Like so!

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Web storage support
    if(localStorage.hashes != "") {
        hashes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hashes"));
        if(hashes) {
            for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
                // Do Stuff
            }
        } else {
            hashes = [];
        }
    }
    else {
        hashes = [];
    }
}
else {
    // No web storage support
    hashes = [];
}
```

Thanks to jbabey for tips on cleaning up my code some!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could have done a little more debugging before posting this.

Have you tried logging/ adding checks (to see where exactly this issue is coming from and what the error is) ?

But since we're here, here are my tips for localStorage :

- Use modernizr (http://modernizr.com/)

> ```
> if(Modernizr.localstorage){ /* Your code */}
> ```

- Make some generic get and set functions

> ```
> function get(key) {
>
>    if(Modernizr.localstorage) { 
>       if(localStorage[key] != null) {
>         return localStorage[key];
>       }
>    }
>    return null;
> }
>
> function set(key, value) {
>
>    if(Modernizr.localstorage) { 
>       localStorage[key] = value;
>    }
>    return null;
> }
> ```

This is pretty rough, you tweek it to make it safer and respond to your needs

- Put try/catch inside your get and set functions, you don't want write operations to impact your program